# Web Scraping Pop-Up with BeatifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, popupwindow

I am new to Web Scraping and I am trying to automate retrieving parcel information from a car website. I need to get the seller's phone number from each parsed link, but the number is under the Pop-Up

```
from bs4  import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = 0

while page <= 500:
    url = "https://auto.ria.com/uk/search/?indexName=auto,order_auto,newauto_search&categories.main.id=1&country.import.usa.not=-1&price.USD.gte=1111&price.currency=1&abroad.not=0&custom.not=1&page=" + str(page)
    request = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "html.parser")

    cars = soup.find_all("a",class_ = "m-link-ticket")
    if cars != []:
        for links in cars:
            print(links.get('href'))
            page += 1
    else: 
        break
```

I checked many videos, but i don't understand how to do it

Comment: I don't think this will work, because you're using `requests` to fetch the page.  The `requests` module does not understand javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_phone(id_):
    url1 = f"https://auto.ria.com/demo/bu/mainPage/rotator/item/{id_}?type=bu&langId=4"
    url2 = "https://auto.ria.com/users/phones/{id_}?hash={userSecureHash}"

    data = requests.get(url1).json()
    userSecureHash = data["userSecure"]["hash"]

    try:
        phone = requests.get(url2.format(id_=id_, userSecureHash=userSecureHash)).json()
    except:
        return data, []

    out = []
    for p in phone["phones"]:
        out.append(p["phoneFormatted"])

    return data, out


url = "https://auto.ria.com/uk/search/?indexName=auto,order_auto,newauto_search&categories.main.id=1&country.import.usa.not=-1&price.USD.gte=1111&price.currency=1&abroad.not=0&custom.not=1&page=0"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

all_data = []
for a in soup.select("a.address"):
    id_ = a["href"].split("_")[-1].split(".")[0]
    data, phones = get_phone(id_)
    if not data:
        continue
    data.pop("userSecure")
    all_data.append({**data, "phones": phones})

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   isAutoBuy  categoryId    autoId    userId  markaId  modelId  bodyId  stateId          marka    model  year yearLetter yearRaceSlash version city cityLocative                                                                               photoBig                                                                            photoMedium                                                                             photoSmall                                                                           photoRiaSmall                                        photoPath                                       link         race currency  currencyId priceFromText type typeName      USD      EUR        UAH  level               levelExpire topType             phones
0      False           1  34988974  12860231       24     1945       5        5           Ford     Edge  2019         р.             /                    Львові              https://cdn4.riastatic.com/photosnew/auto/photo/ford_edge__509055949f.jpg              https://cdn4.riastatic.com/photosnew/auto/photo/ford_edge__509055949m.jpg              https://cdn4.riastatic.com/photosnew/auto/photo/ford_edge__509055949b.jpg              https://cdn4.riastatic.com/photosnew/auto/photo/ford_edge__509055949sx.jpg              auto/photo/ford_edge__509055949.jpg              /auto_ford_edge_34988974.html   33 тис. км      USD           1                 bu     hide   33 900   31 332  1 261 419    130  2023-08-10T08:42:09.000Z          [(098) 439 76 31]
1      False           1  34819008  11247719       84    39690       2        6     Volkswagen   Passat  2011         р.             /                  Прилуках      https://cdn1.riastatic.com/photosnew/auto/photo/volkswagen_passat__504803346f.jpg      https://cdn1.riastatic.com/photosnew/auto/photo/volkswagen_passat__504803346m.jpg      https://cdn1.riastatic.com/photosnew/auto/photo/volkswagen_passat__504803346b.jpg      https://cdn1.riastatic.com/photosnew/auto/photo/volkswagen_passat__504803346sx.jpg      auto/photo/volkswagen_passat__504803346.jpg      /auto_volkswagen_passat_34819008.html  300 тис. км      USD           1                 bu     hide    8 300    7 671    308 843    104  2023-08-12T09:18:13.000Z          [(050) 012 08 68]
2      False           1  34952066   1911193       48     2622       4       12  Mercedes-Benz  B-Class  2018         р.             /                     Одесі  https://cdn0.riastatic.com/photosnew/auto/photo/mercedes-benz_b-class__508113635f.jpg  https://cdn0.riastatic.com/photosnew/auto/photo/mercedes-benz_b-class__508113635m.jpg  https://cdn0.riastatic.com/photosnew/auto/photo/mercedes-benz_b-class__508113635b.jpg  https://cdn0.riastatic.com/photosnew/auto/photo/mercedes-benz_b-class__508113635sx.jpg  auto/photo/mercedes-benz_b-class__508113635.jpg  /auto_mercedes-benz_b-class_34952066.html    7 тис. км      USD           1                 bu     hide   33 900   31 332  1 261 419     82  2023-08-11T05:52:06.000Z          [(067) 277 03 03]
3      False           1  34894081  12336674        9       96       5       12            BMW       X5  2023         р.             /                     Одесі                 https://cdn2.riastatic.com/photosnew/auto/photo/bmw_x5__506757257f.jpg                 https://cdn2.riastatic.com/photosnew/auto/photo/bmw_x5__506757257m.jpg                 https://cdn2.riastatic.com/photosnew/auto/photo/bmw_x5__506757257b.jpg                 https://cdn2.riastatic.com/photosnew/auto/photo/bmw_x5__506757257sx.jpg                 auto/photo/bmw_x5__506757257.jpg                 /auto_bmw_x5_34894081.html    1 тис. км      USD           1                 bu     hide  112 800  104 255  4 197 288     77  2023-08-11T18:44:43.000Z          [(066) 588 88 01]
4      False           1  34748594  12336674        9       96       5       12            BMW       X5  2023         р.             /                     Одесі                 https://cdn4.riastatic.com/photosnew/auto/photo/bmw_x5__504797374f.jpg                 https://cdn4.riastatic.com/photosnew/auto/photo/bmw_x5__504797374m.jpg                 https://cdn4.riastatic.com/photosnew/auto/photo/bmw_x5__504797374b.jpg                 https://cdn4.riastatic.com/photosnew/auto/photo/bmw_x5__504797374sx.jpg                 auto/photo/bmw_x5__504797374.jpg                 /auto_bmw_x5_34748594.html    1 тис. км      USD           1                 bu     hide  110 800  102 406  4 122 868     76  2023-08-11T18:47:24.000Z          [(066) 588 88 01]
5      False           1  34952912  11530222        9       96       5        9            BMW       X5  2012         р.             /                   Рівному                 https://cdn4.riastatic.com/photosnew/auto/photo/bmw_x5__508132844f.jpg                 https://cdn4.riastatic.com/photosnew/auto/photo/bmw_x5__508132844m.jpg                 https://cdn4.riastatic.com/photosnew/auto/photo/bmw_x5__508132844b.jpg                 https://cdn4.riastatic.com/photosnew/auto/photo/bmw_x5__508132844sx.jpg                 auto/photo/bmw_x5__508132844.jpg                 /auto_bmw_x5_34952912.html  267 тис. км      USD           1                 bu     hide   18 750   17 330    697 688     76  2023-08-11T13:52:07.000Z          [(068) 293 90 40]
6      False           1  34990951   5031482        9       96       5       25            BMW       X5  2015         р.             /                 Чернівцях                 https://cdn0.riastatic.com/photosnew/auto/photo/bmw_x5__509102045f.jpg                 https://cdn0.riastatic.com/photosnew/auto/photo/bmw_x5__509102045m.jpg                 https://cdn0.riastatic.com/photosnew/auto/photo/bmw_x5__509102045b.jpg                 https://cdn0.riastatic.com/photosnew/auto/photo/bmw_x5__509102045sx.jpg                 auto/photo/bmw_x5__509102045.jpg                 /auto_bmw_x5_34990951.html  135 тис. км      USD           1                 bu     hide   40 900   37 802  1 521 889     75  2023-08-12T11:44:07.000Z          [(095) 484 63 42]
7      False           1  34932999  10728379     2233    47858       3       11          Tesla  Model 3  2020         р.             /                    Дніпрі          https://cdn0.riastatic.com/photosnew/auto/photo/tesla_model-3__507614740f.jpg          https://cdn0.riastatic.com/photosnew/auto/photo/tesla_model-3__507614740m.jpg          https://cdn0.riastatic.com/photosnew/auto/photo/tesla_model-3__507614740b.jpg          https://cdn0.riastatic.com/photosnew/auto/photo/tesla_model-3__507614740sx.jpg          auto/photo/tesla_model-3__507614740.jpg          /auto_tesla_model-3_34932999.html   57 тис. км      USD           1                 bu     hide   29 900   27 635  1 112 579     75  2023-08-10T06:58:07.000Z          [(067) 561 21 61]
8      False           1  34809199   5201628        9       96       5       10            BMW       X5  2022         р.             /                     Києві                 https://cdn4.riastatic.com/photosnew/auto/photo/bmw_x5__504561189f.jpg                 https://cdn4.riastatic.com/photosnew/auto/photo/bmw_x5__504561189m.jpg                 https://cdn4.riastatic.com/photosnew/auto/photo/bmw_x5__504561189b.jpg                 https://cdn4.riastatic.com/photosnew/auto/photo/bmw_x5__504561189sx.jpg                 auto/photo/bmw_x5__504561189.jpg                 /auto_bmw_x5_34809199.html    1 тис. км      USD           1                 bu     hide  110 800  102 406  4 122 868     75  2023-08-13T11:00:14.000Z          [(097) 744 26 95]
9      False           1  34979610  12336674        9       96       5       12            BMW       X5  2022         р.             /                     Одесі                 https://cdn1.riastatic.com/photosnew/auto/photo/bmw_x5__508825896f.jpg                 https://cdn1.riastatic.com/photosnew/auto/photo/bmw_x5__508825896m.jpg                 https://cdn1.riastatic.com/photosnew/auto/photo/bmw_x5__508825896b.jpg                 https://cdn1.riastatic.com/photosnew/auto/photo/bmw_x5__508825896sx.jpg                 auto/photo/bmw_x5__508825896.jpg                 /auto_bmw_x5_34979610.html    1 тис. км      USD           1                 bu     hide   89 800   82 997  3 341 458     74  2023-08-11T09:50:50.000Z          [(066) 588 88 01]
```